composite primary key django and timescaledb (postgresql)
I am using django for my backend and postgresql for my database cause I have timeseries data i use timescaledb. i have hypertable called devices. there is a composite primary key on fields created_datetime(timestamp) and device_id(integer). I want to use django built in logging users activities ( LogEntry table), so i should have a model representing the hyper table . how can I do this?
I have tried so many things like creating a model putting created_datetime as primarykey then in adminsite i had error ID “2024-05-06 11:55:21” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?

Is the devices the hypertable which tracks data sample from devices? If yes, you need to build a primary key composite with another field.
https://docs.timescale.com/use-timescale/latest/hypertables/hypertables-and-unique-indexes/
